# WkHtmlToXSharp error on Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, environment, staging

WkHtmlToXSharp is C# wrapper (using P/Invoke) for the excelent Html to PDF conversion library wkhtmltopdf library. https://github.com/TobiTonner/WkHtmlToXSharp

I have two websites on staging Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 environment
One of them let say web site **A** version of website and another one web site **B**.

The WkHtmlToXSharp conversion was working on the **A** version but when I set up an **B** version an conversion not working on that version, I am getting an error:

```
HtmlToPdf conversion failed: Failed loading page http://website/Convert (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore)
```

I was wondering why it is happening and than I pointed **A** website to look in to the the same folder as **B** site is looking. And I was surprised that when I am running **A** conversion working well there, but when I am ruining **B** I am still getting the same error, but the funny thing is that both of sites pointed to the same source code(folder). I am just wondering why it is happend. Both websites has the similar app pool configurations and Enable 32-bit apps set too true in bot of them. Also i was trying to set the same app pool for both websites and still the same thing taking place, conversion on site **A** is working but on **B** site is not.

On my local environment(Windows 7 x64) if I set the same websites conversions working in both cases.

Also I made some changes in code to ignore the errors :
`converter.ObjectSettings.Load.LoadErrorHandling = LoadErrorHandlingType.ignore;`
but it is does not fix the error, only the difference is that now I am getting empty pdf in case of conversion on **B** web site.

I just thinking may be it is something in Windows Server which deny to run/keep in memory two copies of WkHtmlToXSharp.dll or wkhtmltopdf or something kind of like that is going on.

Maybe some one have any ideas about that?

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem. Did you find a solution for this? If yes, please PM me.

Answer (score 0):

See this https://github.com/pruiz/WkHtmlToXSharp/issues/8

> The problem with IIS is that it recycles app. pools from time to time,
>   but during this process any non-managed resources hold by your
>   application may (as in this case) end up not being appropiatelly
>   freed. Also, having more than one AppDomain under you'r IIS
>   application can cause memory corruption, as both AppDomains try to
>   instantiante a WebKit instance under the same process (ie. same
>   process memory/space), and that's another no-way.
>
> The best thing you can do is having a Daemon or Service handling
>   HTML2PDF conversión, and calling it from your web app. using remoting,
>   WS calls, or any other RPC method. This will also help you de-compose
>   your application and making things easier to debug.

Hope it helps.